# Rails migration error: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "number" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm getting a strange Rails migration error.  I'm using the "pg" gem to interact with my Postgres database.  When I try to run a migration which adds a "number" column, I get the following error:

```
www-data@site:~/site/current$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20150115193802 AddDailyClicksToSites: migrating ============================
-- add_column(:sites, :daily_clicks, :number)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "number" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "sites" ADD "daily_clicks" number

                                           ^
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring, as previous migrations with "number" fields have worked just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you've been using `:number` and not `:numeric`?

Comment: Yeah, I think this was the issue.  Using the "number" migrations worked on my development database, so I'm assuming that sqlite has a "number" type but Postgres doesn't.

Comment: Why are you using different databases in development and production? Yes, SQLite is the default but it is terrible default and the Rails guys should be ashamed of themselves for it. There are also stories that ActiveRecord is supposed to provide database portability but those stories are complete nonsense. Set up PostgreSQL in your development and test environments then fix all the bugs and this problem will go away.